# Add to plot curve or line in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, plot

```
plot(model$residuals,
abline(h=0,col="red")
```

when i run abline() function, return this error:

> Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : plot.new has not been called yet

How can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

First plot your residuals then call `abline` seperately:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = 1:10 + rnorm(10))
model <- lm(y ~ x, data = df)
plot(df$x, model$residuals)
abline(h = 0, col = "red")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: sorry i wrote there's an error in my past code, i know that plot and abline are two different function, but in Rmarkdown, the line do not come add at plot.

Comment: @Attila perhaps if you included a reproducible example we could offer better help